# R split string by symbol

Tags: r, string, split

Example:

```
string = "abc|3g"
function(string)
Solution: --> "abc" "3g"
```

Is there any idea how to split in the way as showed in the example?

Answer (score 36):

```
strsplit(string,split='|', fixed=TRUE)
```

This is the possible answer. Other solutions?

Comment: You can also look at packages `stringr` and `stringi`. A variation of your answer would be `strsplit(string, "\\|")[[1]]` using two backslashes to escape the special symbol `|`.

Answer (score 2):

A `stringr` option, using [`str_split_1`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html?q=str_split_1#ref-usage), a shortcut for `strsplit(...)[[1]]`.

```r
library(stringr)
str_split_1(string, "\\|")
```

Another `stringr` possibility is to use the more generic `str_split`. I use the pattern `\\|` to escape the special symbol `|`.

```r
#Returns a list of length 1
str_split(string, "\\|")

#Returns a character vector
unlist(str_split(string, "\\|"))
str_split(string, "\\|")[[1]]
```