# R-Converting a character to a vector

Tags: r, character

I have a character which looks like this.

```
df  =   "x ,  y,  z"
```

I want to convert it to a vector. Below is my desired output.

```
df = c("x" ,  "y",  "z")
```

Anybody got an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Try `strsplit("x ,  y,  z", split = ",  ")[[1]]`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842264/r-split-string-by-symbol

Comment: Maybe with `stringr`: `df <- str_replace_all(df, " ", "") %>%  str_split_fixed(",",3 )`

Comment: Thank you all for the solution. It worked for me.